# Why does binding Text to TextBox not work in Avalonia?

Tags: c#, data-binding, avaloniaui

I am new to MVVM and Avalonia and learn it by watching a course on YouTube to create an explorer app. So far I created a super simple explorer like this:
[image]
Here is the *MainWindow.axaml*:

```xml
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="using:AvaloniaMVVMExplorer.ViewModels"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:Avalonia.Xaml.Interactivity;assembly=Avalonia.Xaml.Interactivity"
        xmlns:ia="clr-namespace:Avalonia.Xaml.Interactions.Core;assembly=Avalonia.Xaml.Interactions"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
        x:Class="AvaloniaMVVMExplorer.Views.MainWindow"
        Icon="/Assets/avalonia-logo.ico"
        Title="AvaloniaMVVMExplorer"
        WindowState="Maximized"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Design.DataContext>
        <!-- This only sets the DataContext for the previewer in an IDE,
             to set the actual DataContext for runtime, set the DataContext property in code (look at App.axaml.cs) -->
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Design.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" 
                 Text="{Binding CurrentFilePath}"/>

        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" 
                 x:Name="PathsLB"
                 Items="{Binding DirectoriesAndFiles}" 
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFileEntity}">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <ia:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="DoubleTapped">
                    <ia:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OpenCommand}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=PathsLB, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
                </ia:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

And here is *MainWIndowViewModel.cs*:

```cs
using ReactiveUI;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Input;
using AvaloniaMVVMExplorer.ViewModels.Base;
using AvaloniaMVVMExplorer.ViewModels.Commands;
using AvaloniaMVVMExplorer.ViewModels.FileViewModels;
using AvaloniaMVVMExplorer.ViewModels.FileViewModels.Base;

namespace AvaloniaMVVMExplorer.ViewModels
{
    internal class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region Properties
        private string? currentFilePath;
        public string? CurrentFilePath
        {
            get { return currentFilePath; } 
            set { currentFilePath = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<FileEntityViewModel>? directoriesAndFiles;
        public ObservableCollection<FileEntityViewModel>? DirectoriesAndFiles
        {
            get { return directoriesAndFiles; }
            set { directoriesAndFiles = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private FileEntityViewModel? selectedFileEntity;
        public FileEntityViewModel? SelectedFileEntity
        {
            get { return selectedFileEntity; }
            set { selectedFileEntity = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Commands
        public ICommand OpenCommand { get; }
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            DirectoriesAndFiles = new ObservableCollection<FileEntityViewModel>();

            OpenCommand = new DelegateCommand(Open);

            foreach (var logicalDrive in Directory.GetLogicalDrives())
            {
                DirectoriesAndFiles.Add(new DirectoryViewModel(logicalDrive));
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region CommandMethods
        private void Open(object parameter)
        {
            if (parameter is DirectoryViewModel directoryViewModel)
            {
                CurrentFilePath = directoryViewModel.FullName;

                DirectoriesAndFiles?.Clear();

                var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(CurrentFilePath ?? "");

                foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories()) 
                {
                    DirectoriesAndFiles?.Add(new DirectoryViewModel(directory));
                }

                foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
                {
                    DirectoriesAndFiles?.Add(new FileViewModel(file));
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Every Binding works fine except this one `<TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding CurrentFilePath}"/>`. The binding is to show the user current path, but the Text of TextBox doesn't change even if *CurrentFilePath* is changed.
What could be the reason of this? What am I doing wrong? Thanks!
Full project: https://github.com/CrackAndDie/Avalonia-MVVM-Explorer

Comment: Try setting the Data Context , like this could work: '<TextBox Grid.Row="0"
         Text="{Binding CurrentFilePath, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />

Comment: I set the DataContext, you can see it by the link to the full project. Settings RelativeSource gives me the error ```Could not find a matching property accessor for 'CurrentFilePath' on 'AvaloniaMVVMExplorer.Views.MainWindow'``` because I don't have anything in the MainWindow.axaml.cs file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with your `PropertyChanged` notification.

```cs
    internal class ViewModelBase : ReactiveObject
    {
        #region PropetryChangedHandler
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? BasePropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
        {
            BasePropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Nothing happens because ReactiveObject already implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` which WPF/Avalonia looks for which using `Bind`.

You must either change your view model to simply Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or change directly in your ViewModel to use ReactiveObject methods `set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _memberField, value);`

Since your ViewModel implements `ReactiveObject` it must use the operations provided by it to trigger change notifications.  ReactiveObject is a class provided by [ReactiveUI](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/data-binding/change-notifications).  ReactiveUI can be quite valuable to learn as it does provide many useful mechanisms to keep your code concise while implementing MVVM.  However ReactiveUI is built on [rx.net](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive), understanding Rx.net is advisiable to use ReactiveUI, but can be a steep learning curve to start with.

I suggest Implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`, which would result in the following in your `ViewModelBase`:

```
    internal class ViewModelBase  : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

If you stick to the ReactiveUI route then you would change:

```
        public string? CurrentFilePath
        {
            get { return currentFilePath; } 
            set { currentFilePath = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
```

To:

```
        public string? CurrentFilePath
        {
            get => currentFilePath;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref currentFilePath, value);
        }
```