# How to set property in viewmodel from event in MainWindow class in AvaloniaUI

Tags: c#, avaloniaui

I'm newbee in AvaloniaUI and MVVM so don't beat me up too much pls!
I am trying to write a project based on a typical template.
The MainWindow class has an event that triggers when a menu item is clicked.

```
namespace TTools.Views
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
       ...

        public void OnFindDoublesCommand()
        {
             ... // Something do and want to set Output
        }
```

And after the command is finished, I want to pass the result to a string variable Output in the MainWindowViewModel class

```
namespace TTools.ViewModels
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            Output = "";
        }

        public string Output { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Which in turn is bound to the control

```
<TextBlock Margin="16" Text="{Binding Output}" Name="Filename"></TextBlock>
```

How do I set it from the event?

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
I looked at how this is implemented in the example from

[Avalonia.Samples](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia.Samples)

And some code from here

[Why does binding Text to TextBox not work in Avalonia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75110531/why-does-binding-text-to-textbox-not-work-in-avalonia)

And I've done a little rework.

remove all events from MainWindow class.
He stayed clean.

```
namespace TTools.Views
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

add code to ViewModelBase class:

```
public class ViewModelBase : ReactiveObject
    {
        public new event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

And I added the following code to the MainWindowViewModel:

```
namespace TTools.ViewModels
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private string _Output;
        public string Output
        {
            get => _Output;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _Output, value);
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            Output = "";

            OnFindDoublesCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(FindDoubles);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This command will call void FindDoubles.
        /// </summary>
        // Note: We use the interface ICommand here because this makes things more flexible. 
        public ICommand OnFindDoublesCommand { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Find doubles and output
        /// </summary>
        public void FindDoubles()
        {
             //Work
        }
```

And MainWindow.axaml

```
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="using:TTools.ViewModels"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
        Width="800"
        Height="450"
        x:CompileBindings="True"
        x:DataType="vm:MainWindowViewModel"
        x:Class="TTools.Views.MainWindow"
        Icon="/Assets/avalonia-logo.ico"
        Title="TTools">

    <Design.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Design.DataContext>

    <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="_Tools">
 
                <MenuItem Name="FindDoubles" Header="Поиск дубликатов типов" Command="{Binding OnFindDoublesCommand}"/>
                <Separator/>

            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <!-- This will correctly detect the absence of a property called Checker -->
            <TextBlock Margin="16" Text="{Binding Output, Mode=OneWay}" Name="Output"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

**It's work! The end)**

Comment: You do not need `PropertyChanged` event in your base class, that is already all implemented in the `ReactiveObject` you are inheriting.

Comment: @Jammer Yes, I found that out, too. Thx