# AvaloniaUI - access ViewModel from code behind

Tags: c#, mvvm, reactiveui, avaloniaui

I’m trying to port an old WPF application to Avalonia UI (Reactive MVVM) and thereby learn a bit of Avalonia. In my old app I used a pattern in which I had the code for events (mostly just button clicks, dropdownlists etc.) in the code-behind of the view. So just as a simplified example, the pattern was like this in my WPF app (you can skip over this sections as it's just a basic WPF example showing my pattern):

My view - MainWindow.xaml:

```
  <Window x:Class="WpfTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Greeting}"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

….code behind the view – MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
namespace WpfTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ViewModel myview = new ViewModel();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = myview;  
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myview.Greeting = "Hello";
        //…and here functions from other classes etc. are called
        }
    }
}
```

….finally the ViewModel – ViewModel.cs:

```
namespace WpfTest
{
    internal class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void RaisePropertyChange(string propertyname)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
            }
        }


        private string _greeting;
        public string Greeting
        {
            get { return _greeting; }
            set
            {
                _greeting = value;
                RaisePropertyChange("Greeting");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This pattern worked perfectly for my needs also when creating quite complex applications even with my limited abilities and often also allowed me to recycle a lot of code as the Models are still separated from the rest of the program.
I’m aware that the MVVM “purists” would say that the code behind of the view should be empty and that’s also where I start struggling because all the tutorials on Avalonia UI seem to do everything that I did in the ViewModel by Binding to commands (and in fact don’t seem to do a lot outside the ViewModels at all). I assume that this would be the most professional way to do things, however I would like to keep my old WPF pattern because it would allow me to recycle lots of code. However I can’t even get the basic example above to work in Avalonia MVVM. So let’s say  the ViewModel looks like this:

```
namespace AvaloniaTest.ViewModels
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private string? greeting;
        public string? Greeting
        {
            get => greeting;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref greeting, value);
        }
    }
}
```

And the code behind the View (basically identical to the WPF version):

```
namespace AvaloniaTest.Views
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        MainWindowViewModel myview = new MainWindowViewModel();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = myview;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myview.Greeting = "Hello";
        }
    }
}
```

When I try it like this, nothing happens on the UI when I click the button. I guess that has to do with the ViewModel being already set in App.axaml.cs and the DataContext I set in code doesn’t do anything to the active View. However, I haven’t found/understood how to access the actual ViewModel from code behind – is this even possible at all?

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76007852/how-to-set-property-in-viewmodel-from-event-in-mainwindow-class-in-avaloniaui) question the answer was again to create a ReactiveCommand in the ViewModel. All the official and unofficial samples I found, also only use Commands in the ViewModel, however the documentation mentions that one can also use events instead.

Comment: What about `(this.DataContext as MainWindowViewModel).Greeting = "Hello";` ?

Comment: Apart from the previous line, I would be one to also recommend switching this to commands - I've made some [simple sample](https://github.com/Tatranskymedved/WpfPromholComplementary_1) some time ago and it includes both basic [RelayCommand](https://github.com/Tatranskymedved/WpfPromholComplementary_1/blob/master/RelayCommand.cs) and example of its usage in [ViewModel](https://github.com/Tatranskymedved/WpfPromholComplementary_1/blob/master/MainViewModel.cs). Avalonia however have its own things inside, take this just as basic meta where to start.

Comment: What does the xaml for avalonia looks like?

Comment: @Tatranskymedved thx, that works! Before writing the post I already had tried `MainWindowViewModel myview = (MainWindowViewModel)this.DataContext; myview.Greeting = "Hello!";` which is the same thing and now also works correctly - so I must have had some other mistake somewhere in my code before. Nonetheless I will consider switching to commands in the ViewModel.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen xaml for Avalonia looks just like the one for WPF (except for the WPF Window declarations header). Even though I have the solution now - I'm still wondering why Avalonia just seems to ignore it when I try to set a new ViewModel as DataContext.

Answer (score 2):

The ViewModel already exists and is held in the `DataContext`. To use it as your ViewModel just cast it using whichever method you prefer

```
DataContext as MainWindowViewModel
```

or

```
(MainWindowViewModel)DataContext
```