# MVVM Avalonia call a method from view to viewmodel doesn't change binded property

Tags: avalonia

After the start of my app I want to setup a lot in my models, I have setup() methods in the MV and in the Model. A bool property was set to true and I want to display this with the state of a check box.
Both, the VM and the Model has bool-Properties and the PropertyChanged Event is raised from the Model to the VM to set the Property in the VM.
All is fine when I set the property

- in the constructor of the VM (the VM-Property)
- call the VM-Setup-method in the VM from the VM-constructor (in these method set the VM-Property)
- call the Model-Setup method from the VM-Setup-method via an Model-Instance and set the Model-Property

I try to folloing the "rule modelview doesn't know the view" and call the MV-Setup method from the view with an instance of MV, but now, the checkbox wasn't set.

I guess it is somethig about the threads? Or is this a problem of Avalonia? The inherit of the ObservableObject isn't the problem as well, I tested it.

For test purposes now, I binded a textblock to these property, but the same behavior.

Here are the excerpts from my test code

MainWindow.axaml - these is the textblock

```
  <TextBlock Height="100" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="AliceBlue" Text="{Binding AutoOpen}"/>
```

MainWindow

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    MainViewModel viewModel = new MainViewModel();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       viewModel.SetupVM();
        
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    SerialPortModel SerialPortModel;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private bool _autoOpen;
    public bool AutoOpen
    {
        get { return _autoOpen; }
        set { _autoOpen = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AutoOpen")); }
    }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        SerialPortModel = new();
        SerialPortModel.PropertyChanged += SerialPortModel_PropertyChanged;
        SetupVM();
    }
    public bool SetupVM()
    {
        //AutoOpen = true; 
        SerialPortModel.SetUp();
        return true;
    }
    private void SerialPortModel_PropertyChanged(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case "AutoOpen":
                AutoOpen = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
 internal class SerialPortModel :INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _autoOpen;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        public SerialPortModel() 
        {
            //AutoOpen = true;
        }
        public void SetUp()
        {

            AutoOpen = true;
        }
        internal bool AutoOpen
        {
            get { return _autoOpen; }
            set { _autoOpen = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AutoOpen")); }
        }
    }
```

I found no exact explanation how to call a method from the View or how to raise an event or use a command to initiate something from View's code behind into the ViewModel or deeper in the Model.

The reason for that is to initiate a setup process in the model, load something, set up a serial port etcetera...but all after the app is completely started. So I have to wait for "Loaded" in the View and raise something....

Or is this the complete wrong idea?

Comment: After more tests, the behavior is clear. The binded Textblock text is set if I call the setup -method from the ViewModel in the constructor. If I call the same method from the View via an instance from the VM, it doesn'work.

Comment: I found something that works and calls the VM-method and the binded properties where updated.,  It's about DataContext. (this.DataContext as MainViewModel).ComboBoxDeviceSelectionChanged(cb.SelectedItem.ToString()); This is described in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76372302/avaloniaui-access-viewmodel-from-code-behind the answer from Tatranskymedved

Answer (score 0):

I got it after hours, but this is clear, I instanciated a new ViewModel Object instead of using the alredy existing. It's described exactly here:
[Answer from Mellow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77547625/13300392)
The DataContext holds the existing instance. Thanks  @Mellow

Comment: You say "already existing" but with any of the default templates there would be no existing view model, by default DataContext is null and you must assign it.  This can be done in code behind (typical method when using DI) or it can be done in XAML.

Comment: It´s automatically instanciated (VS Template for an Avalonia Project) in the App.xaml.cs. Therefore it´s axisting for me.